# Approach to securing test data for public repositories

Tags: integration-testing

We have setup nightly testing for an open source project (MERN stack). The Selenium tests require test data which we do not want to not make public. Initially we tried to keep test data as environment variables in the build server (CircleCI) but this approach is not scalable. We do not own any infrastructure - so any database or storage bucket based solutions will need additional cost which will not be feasible based on the org's current budget.Is there a smart solution to keep the test data files secure at no additional cost?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the challenge is that you need *somewhere* to put that data.  If you're trying to do this without paying any providers, the best I can suggest is Amazon's free tier for either S3 storage or a database. https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Those could be securely accessed from CircleCI by just storing the API keys as project variables.

[CircleCI's AWS S3 orb](https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/circleci/aws-s3) encapsulates the install and setup of AWS CLI to simplify this.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-s3: circleci/aws-s3@1.0.2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: 'circleci/node:10'
    steps:
      - checkout
      - aws-s3/copy:
          from: 's3://your-s3-bucket-name/test_data/somefile.ext'
          to: test_data.ext
      - run: # your test code here
```